# How to get JsonString to JsonArray in Android

Tags: android, json, exception, getjson, type-mismatch

We are getting response like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 124,
    membershipid: ,
    title: MEMBER
  },
  {
    id: 125,
    membershipid: 4123,
    title: TWOYEARDIRECTORR
  },
  {
    id: 126,
    membershipid: ,
    title: TWOYEARDIRECTOR
  },
  {
    id: 127,
    membershipid: ,
    title: MEMBER
  }
]
```

We are trying convert JsonString to JsonArray 
Our code

`ServiceHandler` is user defined class which extends `HttpClient`

```
String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url_check, ServiceHandler.GET);
Log.d("result : ", jsonStr);
try {
    JSONObject tt=new JSONObject(jsonStr);
}
```

But it shows `org.json.JSON.typeMismatch`

Can anyone help me out
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `[{id:124,membershipid:,title:MEMBER}..]` is not valid json ... `[{"id":124,"membershipid":"","title":"MEMBER"}..]` is

Comment: @Pavan Alapati you can always check with this http://pro.jsonlint.com/

Comment: check your json using jsonlint or any other resource that it is valid or not.

Comment: In jsonlint showing valid json

Comment: post your full logcat errors.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are receiving an Array, use `JSONArray` instead of `JSONObject`.

Comment: if using JsonArray also same issue

Comment: we have tested in Json validator,it showing valid json

Comment: @PavanAlapati post the error that you are receiving

Answer (score 1):

The above mentioned JSON is RFC 4627 string. To parses a JSON (RFC 4627) encoded string into the corresponding object. we have to use JSONTokener.

```
JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(json).nextValue();
 String query = object.getString("id");
 String membershipid = object.getString("membershipid");
 String title = object.getString("title");
```

Or else return the JSON as a normal JSON string.
if you are using php for server side , use "`JSON_ENCODE`" to encode a string to json.

Hope it helps.

Comment: We SqlServer and services in .net

Comment: We getting error
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject

Comment: Can you please insert this and let me know.
 JSONArray array=new JSONArray(response);
JSONObject jObj = array.getJSONObject(0);
 String error = jObj.getString("ErrorCode");

Comment: JSONObject array=new JSONObject(response); JSONArray jObj = array.getJSONArray(0); String error = jObj.getString("ErrorCode");
try this

Comment: JsonArray not allowing 0 value & getting error for jobj.getString("id");

Comment: The above metioned response you got?? Its not a valid JSON. https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: The response is  under string 
"my response"

the main problem is this

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
JSONArray tt=new JSONArray (jsonStr);
```